# Why are there multiple different hashing algorithm providers in System.Security.Cryptography?

Tags: .net, cryptography, hash

As documented by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx), there are several providers for many of the different hashing algorithms (e.g. MD5, SHA, RIPE). For each of the algorithms, any available implementation seems to fall into 1 of 3 categories:

- [Algo]**Cng**
- [Algo]**CryptoServiceProvider**
- [Algo]**Managed**

Why are there multiple implementations of any of these hashing algorithms?

What are the differences between the implementations?

What are the practical differences when choosing which implementation to utilize in an application?

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [CNG, CryptoServiceProvider and Managed implementations of HashAlgorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211169/cng-cryptoserviceprovider-and-managed-implementations-of-hashalgorithm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `[Algo]Managed` is a pure-IL implementation of the algorithm.
- `[Algo]CryptoServiceProvider` delegates to CAPI, which allows you to use things such as hardware crypto devices.
- `[Algo]Cng` uses Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG) which is designed to be a replacement for CAPI but is only supported in Vista and Server 2008.

Comment: Ahh, we are so close. Thanks for the answer to questions 1 and 2. Any chance you or anyone else knows the answer to the third question (my major concern) especially when CryptoServiceProvider and Managed are both available?

Comment: That's fascinating! Great answer.

Comment: One would tend to think that Managed code is going to be slower than Native code, especially on crypto code, and even more if you have a hardware device.

Comment: Vinko - I would tend to agree that a purely managed implementation of a crypto algo would be slower than a fully optimized native implementation or dedicated hardware device. However, what about the portability, maintainability, and availability of the different implementations?

Comment: For short messages, the managed code is actually the fastest variant. The native variants only catch up for longer messages. If performance is really important it can be useful to wrap anther library like OpenSSL, at least for short MD5 messages that resulted in a huge performance boost for one of my applications.